# Bigquery tables meta data: type 2 tables are empty but queryable

Tags: google-bigquery

I was wondering why a query on an empty table like `inputs` on the `crypto_bitcoin` dataset returns the desired result!

Let's check the tables metadata:

```
#              project_id      dataset_id                          table_id  creation_time  last_modified_time  row_count     size_bytes  type
# 0  bigquery-public-data  crypto_bitcoin                            blocks  1547490497012       1637478718029     710664      231483216     1
# 1  bigquery-public-data  crypto_bitcoin                            inputs  1547524356605       1637411737414          0              0     2
# 2  bigquery-public-data  crypto_bitcoin                           outputs  1547524350726       1637411717125          0              0     2
# 3  bigquery-public-data  crypto_bitcoin                      transactions  1547491686807       1637478717455  688583399  1532618029551     1
# 4  bigquery-public-data  crypto_bitcoin  transactions-2021-10-28T23_18_45  1635477564574       1635477564574  682200389  1520464709331     6
```

These queries appear to report 0 bytes for `inputs` and `outputs`, so they're free.

However, the following query returns a result:

```
query = """
SELECT inputs.value as value
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.inputs` as inputs
LIMIT 10
"""
transactions = crypto_bitcoin.query_to_pandas_safe(query, max_gb_scanned=27)
print(transactions)


                   value
0      1121913.000000000
1      2530000.000000000
2     43852957.000000000
3      6064813.000000000
4       200000.000000000
5    921665002.000000000
6       159497.000000000
7       266185.000000000
8  37268226789.000000000
9      9493833.000000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `inputs` and `outputs` are both views so they themselves store no data which is why the rows and byte size are both 0.  They do both reference the `transactions` dataset so the sizing for that would be applicable.